# Tooltips show at cursor make pywinauto throws out ElementAmbiguousError

Tags: tooltip, pywinauto, windows-11

I am write a script that will open a Select Folder system dialog, script works perfectly then I found that when the cursor point accident to element on dialog, the tooltip shows up and my script failed, it throws out the error message:

```
*pywinauto.findwindows.ElementAmbiguousError: There are 2 elements that match the criteria {'backend': 'uia', 'process': 19852}*
```

code to open dialog:

```
openDlg= katApp.child_window(title="Select Folder", control_type="Window",found_index=0)    
txtFolder = openDlg.child_window(title="Folder:", control_type="Edit",found_index=0)
txtFolder.draw_outline(colour='green', thickness=2)
txtFolder.type_keys(projectPath + "~",with_spaces=True)
btnSelectFolder = openDlg.child_window(title="Select Folder", control_type="Button",found_index=0)
btnSelectFolder.click_input()
openDlg.wait_not("visible")
tviTestCasesFolder = katApp.child_window(title="Test Cases", control_type="TreeItem",found_index=0)    
tviTestCasesFolder.wait('exists ready active',timeout=30)
```

The tooltip shows accident like this:
[image]

It is very disappointed since I could bring my script to other machine for running and then tooltips accident show. Could you please help me out? Or show me the solution if any

I try to hide the tooltips by using registry and adjust the key Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse\MouseHoverTime but still don't work.

Comment: Which line is exactly failed? And could you please provide full traceback? This error message seems not listing the whole search criteria.

Comment: Also it is possible to call `.move_mouse_input(coords=(0, 0))` for the main window or for the dialog.